# set custom date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I saw a jQuery library [here](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/0.4.5/) for date and I set it with default date.

this is for set current date:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#enddate").pDatepicker({
            persianDigit: true,
            viewMode: "year",
            position: "auto",
            autoClose: true,
            format: false,
            observer: false,
            altField: false,
            format : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
            inputDelay: 800 
        });
    });
```

for `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` format I want set my custom year like
(1392-12-11 13:51:11)

according the DOC,It says I must use

```
$( "#enddate" ).pDatepicker("setDate",[1392,12,11,13,51,11] );
```

but it does not work.

how can combine these codes?

this is html code:

```
<input type="text " placeholder="pick up date" id="enddate" name="enddate" tabindex="8">
```

Comment: Per the docs you linked to: _"format (string) i.e. 'mm/dd/yyyy' - the date format, combination of d, dd, m, mm, yy, yyy."_ Looks like the format you're trying to use is not supported...

Comment: I think I found the issue you are having. Check my edited answer below

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one option. If you want to set also the time, not just the date, you need to enable the `timePicker`.
The documentation is not very clear about it.

You need to add this line to the DatePicker initialisation

```
timePicker: {enabled: true}
```

So it will look like this:

```
$("#enddate").pDatepicker({
  persianDigit: true,
  viewMode: "year",
  position: "auto",
  autoClose: true,
  format: false,
  observer: false,
  altField: false,
  format : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
  inputDelay: 800,
  timePicker: {enabled: true}
});
```

You also have more options, for the `timePicker`, and you should define them on the initialisation. Check the documentation to see more options.

Since you already fixed the typo, I only leave this comment:

For javascript coding standards you should use CamelCase, so the `id` should be `endDate`. This will make your code easier to read.